# Does Not Assigning a Variable Name To a Type Only Work In Swift Playgrounds Learning Exercises for iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm a noob whose enjoying the use of Swift Playgrounds on iPad where you get more experience coding in Swift.  On the level Floating Islands I noticed the following code is allowed:

```
world.place(Block(), atColumn: 2, row: 2)
```

This kind of throws me off because we don't have to worry about creating an instance and assigning it to a variable.  If I wanted to go back and modify this Block() instance, is it possible without having it assigned to a variable?  I'm curious if this is how actual development works when building an app for the iPhone or is this only applicable to learning exercises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I wanted to go back and modify this Block() instance, is it possible without having it assigned to a variable?

No. You'd need the variable as a reference.

Your intuition about what's going on here is correct. We could have said:

```
let b = Block()
world.place(b, atColumn: 2, row: 2)
```

But since nothing else is done with `b`, it is optimized away by the compiler, and we end up under the hood with exactly the same code that's actually used:

```
world.place(Block(), atColumn: 2, row: 2)
```

Because of that optimization, no bad thing happens if you *do* use the first form, so by all means go ahead and use it if it makes you feel more comfortable. (In some ways, the first form is better for debugging purposes, as it gives you something to step through and examine.)

However (to go back to the original point), as you rightly imply, if we *did* want to modify this Block object here, we *would* need to have assigned it to a variable, as otherwise we'd have no reference through which to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can actually write production code this way. I'm not familiar with the actual example, but it looks like you just create a Blocks object and place it at a particular location.

If you want to change it later it depends on the `world` object, whether you can get the object at the specified location and edit it. Sometimes this requires getting a reference, changing it and then saving it back, or maybe the `world` object allows you to edit the object at that location, where you don't need to have a reference.